# Subquery in select clause in symfony2 in select clause

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, subquery

I want to use symfony2 query builder in repository, to create following query:

```
SELECT c.name,
       (
         SELECT COUNT(1)
         FROM product
         WHERE product.cat_id = c.id
       ) products
FROM category c
ORDER BY category.id ASC
```

May I use query builder for this purpose, and how to structure query builder?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a need of subquery here. It can simply be achieved with `count` and `group by`,

Assuming that you have defined correct relation between `Product` and `Catergory` this DQL query should work.

Include this in your category repository

```
$categories = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->select('c.name,count(p.id)')
                    ->leftJoin('c.products','p')
                    ->groupBy('c.id')
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```